# Using html elements attribute to locate and alter another html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to append a active class to the particular div that is referenced by hashtag.

Ex:

```
<a href="#cont1">content1</a>
<a href="#cont2">content2</a>
<a href="#cont3">content3</a>

<div id="cont1">lorem ipsum dummy content</div>
<div id="cont1">lorem ipsum dummy content</div>
<div id="cont1">lorem ipsum dummy content</div>
```

I would like to append one class to each div on hyperlink click.I mean if i click the anchor tag with href "#cont1" , one class name needs to append for div id "cont1".

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use value of `href` attribute as selector. `$('a').on('click', function() { $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active'); });` Check [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ztfb0ycm/)

Answer (score 0):

id should be unique and you can't add the same id for div  use class instead

```
<a onclick="test()">content1</a>
 <div class="cont1">lorem ipsum dummy content</div>
 //this is the javascript 
 function test(){
   $(".cont1").addClass('active');
 }
```